# Why is my gameobject moving to the wrong place?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attaching the following script to a GO that i want to control the hoist GO. The hoist is supposed to move to the target, but winds up moving to the GO that i have to the script attached to instead. what's causing this and how do i fix it?

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

    public class HoistTest : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject hoist;
        public Transform target;
        public float speed;

        void OnMouseUp()
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            hoist.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to understand your question correctly: but don't you want to do the following?

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(hoist.transform.position, target.position, step);
```

so, moving the hoist object towards the target position. Sorry if I misunderstood the request.

Comment: you're exactly right.  can't believe i missed that.  thanks for the help!